# How to make my app device owner through code

Tags: android, android-studio, kiosk-mode

I want to develop a kiosk mode app and need my app to be device owner. I have tried the command `adb shell dpm set-device-owner` and it works. But I want to publish this app so I can't obviously do this to all the devices. I have read in some posts that I can write

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner ...");
```

I wrote this in my onCreate but it doesn't do anything. Is it related to my device not being rooted or am I missing something?

Comment: To run these commands on the device from code, the device has to be rooted, and second if there's an already set device owner this command will not work.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing, but I don't think it could be done using java/kotlin code, this so called "Device owner provisioning" is documented here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision.html#device_owner_provisioning_via_nfc